# How to determine specific change $e/m$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, charge, electromagnetic-induction

Determination of the specific electron charge.

They are brought to velocity V by a known initial accelerating voltage Ub. Then the electrons
fly through a plate capacitor which is located in a homogeneous magnetic field. Electric field E, magnetic field B and initial flight direction V of the electrons are perpendicular to each other in pairs.
In the case that the effects of the E- and B-fields just compensate each other (straight-line flight of the electrons), derive a formula for the calculation of the specific
electron charge from the experimentally given quantities  (E, B, U.)

I started with E(kin)=E(pot)

1/2 * mv^2 = e*U

E=F/e

What should I do next?

There is F Lorentz = eE + eVB

How to connect all the steps?